# Prove that $(\exists!x)(A(x))\iff(\exists x)(A(x)\wedge(\forall y)(A(x)\wedge A(y)\implies x=y)$

Tags: logic

$$(\exists!x)(A(x))\iff(\exists x)(A(x)\wedge(\forall y)(A(x)\wedge A(y))\implies x=y)$$

This is extremely intuitive, there is only one $x$ that satisfies the property $A$ if and only if there exists an $x$ such that $A$ and for every $y$ that satisfies $A$ we have $x=y$, which shows uniqueness. But I surprisingly fail at proving that bi-conditional ***formally*** speaking.

Here is my attempt

$$\begin{align}
(\exists!x)A(x)&\equiv(\exists x)A(x)\wedge\sharp(\text{Set of $x$ that satisfy $A$})=1.\\
&\equiv ??
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is “\exists!” for you? It's just a shorthand for RHS of your formula. There is no quantifier “$\exists!$”.

Comment: Dear Michael.  My textbook defines ∃! as: *For any open sentence P(x), the proposition ( ∃!x)P(x) is read 'there exists a unique x such that P(x)' and is true if and only if P(x) has exactly one element.*

Comment: So, as observed, is pointless to prove such equivalence: they are equal by definition or *definitionally equal*.

Comment: What would be the meaning of "x is unique"? I think it's just "every y having the property, is equal to x". The point is you can translate a formal formula to an English sentence in different ways (and vice versa).

Comment: Ok thanks, and is there any difference between $$(\exists x)(A(x)\wedge(\forall y)(A(x)\wedge A(y)\implies x=y)$$ and$$(\exists x)(A(x)\wedge(\forall y)(\forall z)(A(y)\wedge A(z)\implies y=z)$$

Comment: @logician: Your question in your last comment can likewise be answered in two ways, and you should have no trouble finding the model-theoretic 'proof' in the manner I showed in my answer. As for the formal proof that the two formulae are equivalent (different but equivalent), you should ask a separate question and specify if you are given some particular formal rules, since different mathematicians will use different sets of rules (for all kinds of reasons like convenience, elegance, utility, ...).

Comment: "P(x) has exactly one element" is a quite high-level definition: it involves set, cardinality, and "one". Usually $\exists !$ is defined using more primitive terms such as the formula you posted. Another one (used at least by Russell) is $\exists c.\forall x. (P(x) \iff x=c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Michael*'s point is that in a **formal** system there must be **formal** rules for manipulating symbols. So your provided textbook definition is **not formal**. In other words, we can say that there is simply a rule that allows us to rewrite either side of your equivalence into the other, and nothing to be proven. Note also that your second "$A(x)$" is redundant, and I'll ignore it for the rest of my answer (you can easily see how to include it after you've understood my answer).

But if you are not talking about a formal proof, but a **model-theoretic** proof, then you are no longer asking for a formal derivation, namely a sequence of statements allowed by the formal rules. Instead you would be asking for a proof **outside** the formal language that shows that given any model satisfying one side, it also satisfies the other. This we can 'do' as follows:

Given any model satisfying $\exists! x ( A(x) )$, let $x$ be a unique object such that $A(x)$ is true. Then $A(x)$ is true. Also, given any $y$, if $A(y)$ is true, then $y$ must be the same as $x$ because $x$ was unique. Thus $\forall y ( A(y) \rightarrow x = y )$ is true. Therefore $\exists x ( A(x) \land \forall y ( A(y) \rightarrow x = y )$ is true.

Similarly you can check that given any model satisfying $\exists x ( A(x) \land \forall y ( A(y) \rightarrow x = y )$ there will be a unique object $x$ such that $A(x)$ is true. Basically it exists because the given condition already guarantees existence. Also, it must be unique because any object satisfying $A$ is equal to it.

If you found this argument not satisfying, as if it is circular reasoning, it is indeed circular, because in our reasoning about models we are already using intuition corresponding to the equivalence we are purporting to prove! That is why some things must be accepted as either axioms that cannot be proven, or as definitions such as in this case. We simply **define** uniqueness according to the formal statement.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks for your effort

Comment: @logician: You're welcome. Also, if any part is not clear feel free to ask.